# Autoware built with CUDA support: 60 packages had stderr output

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am installing Autoware 1.13.0 using the source code. I have ROS melodic installed on Ubuntu 18.04.4 with CUDA 10.0 and gcc 6.5. I have NVIDIA GTX 10 series with 4GB.

After setting up everything, I have built the autoware with CUDA support and I got the following after the build finished.

Please help me what this means.

Summary: 164 packages finished [22min 27s]

60 packages had stderr output: adi_driver astar_search autoware_camera_lidar_calibrator autoware_connector autoware_driveworks_gmsl_interface autoware_driveworks_interface autoware_health_checker autoware_pointgrey_drivers citysim costmap_generator data_preprocessor decision_maker dp_planner imm_ukf_pda_track kitti_player kvaser lane_planner lanelet2_core lanelet2_examples lanelet2_extension lanelet2_io lanelet2_projection lanelet2_python lanelet2_routing lanelet2_traffic_rules lanelet2_validation lanelet_aisan_converter libwaypoint_follower lidar_apollo_cnn_seg_detect lidar_euclidean_cluster_detect lidar_localizer lidar_point_pillars lidar_shape_estimation map_file microstrain_driver mpc_follower mqtt_socket ndt_cpu ndt_gpu object_map op_ros_helpers op_simulation_package op_utilities pcl_omp_registration pixel_cloud_fusion points_downsampler points_preprocessor qpoases_vendor range_vision_fusion road_occupancy_processor sick_ldmrs_tools trafficlight_recognizer vector_map_server vision_darknet_detect vision_segment_enet_detect vision_ssd_detect vlg22c_cam way_planner waypoint_maker waypoint_planner

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346599/autoware-built-with-cuda-support:--60-packages-had-stderr-output/) by [omkard](https://answers.ros.org/users/51732/omkard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 64 on 2020-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@dynamicsoorya This is expected. Many of the packages have `stderr` output but, as long as they compile to completion, it's not really an issue. If any of them failed, you would see "Summary: X packages finished [time]; Y packages failed; Z packages skipped."

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2020-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [omkard](https://answers.ros.org/users/51732/omkard/) on 2020-03-12**:
I did not get any packages as failed. I think I am good then.

Thank you, Josh.